# Mal funcionamiento de checkbox en formulario

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla en la cual creé un campo `boolean` llamado `equipment` el cual alimento desde un formulario, es un checkbox y deseo que al ser seleccionado se guarde en el campo el `valor 1`, sino se selecciona o se deselecciona el `valor 0`.

Tengo este código

```
<div class="form-group text-left mb-4">
    <strong>{{ Form::label('equipment', trans('Equipment')) }}</strong>
    <div>
        <label class="pr-2"> 
            {{ Form::checkbox('equipment', $profile->equipment) }} {{ __('Equipment and tools is brought along') }}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Si hago lo siguiente `{{ Form::checkbox('equipment', $profile->equipment) }} {{ __('Equipment and tools is brought along') }}` me da un error `ErrorException Attempt to read property "equipment" on null`

si hago lo siguiente para corregirlo `{{ Form::checkbox('equipment', $profile->equipment ?? '') }} {{ __('Equipment and tools is brought along') }}` me envía el valor `NULL` al controllador

Requiero que pueda envíar el valor y además leer el de la base de datos, para que se mantenga seleccionado al editar si es el caso.

Me funciona con los array que leo desde una tabla pivote, pero así como está arriba, no.

```
<div class="form-group text-left mb-4">
    <strong>{{ Form::label('skills', trans('Skills')) }}</strong>
    <div>
        @foreach($skills as $skill)
            <label class="pr-2"> 
                {{ Form::checkbox('skills[]', $skill->id) }} {{ __($skill->skill) }}
            </label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Y seguro que `$profile` si llega a la vista con algún valor?, por qué el error te esta indicando que llega NULL y por eso no puedes aplicar la sintaxis de `$objeto->clave`

Comment: En este momento no, porque estoy en el registro (Uso el mismo formulario para registrar y editar), deseo que pueda envíar el valor al controlador para guardarlo, en caso que lo seleecione el usuario, y luego leerlo en la vista de editar si está  guardado el valor en la BD

Comment: Para evitar el error de carga de la vista hago lo siguiente `{{ Form::checkbox('equipment', $profile->equipment ?? '') }} {{ __('Equipment and tools is brought along') }}` pero necesito que al seleccionar el checkbox me envíe el valor al controlador, de momento lo envía `NULL`

Comment: Así funciona `{{ Form::checkbox('equipment', NULL, false) }} {{ __('Equipment and tools is brought along') }}`

Comment: Pero no me resuelve el problema

Comment: Lo solucioné creando dos formularios, uno para el registro y otro para editar